# How do I craft Shroomite Armor?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have gotten to hardcore mode, and this is supposedly the best ranger armor. How do I create it?

Answer (score 1):

The [wiki search](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shroomite_armor) should have been your first objective before asking.

The only material needed for its craft is **Shroomite bar**

Shroomite bar is obtained by mixing, on a **Autohammer** (sold by the Truffle NPC), a **Chlorophyte bar** and **glowing mushrooms** (15 for each bar, so you'll need a lot of them)
Chlorophyte bars, if you haven't obtained it yet, are made of Chlorophyte ores which are harvestable by using at least the hallowed pickaxe.

> Crafting a full set with a single helmet requires **54** Shroomite Bars (or **810** Glowing Mushrooms and **324** Chlorophyte Ore). A full set with all three helmets requires **1170** Glowing Mushrooms and **468** Chlorophyte Ore.